# What is this notation in Chrome Devtools Autocomplete?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, google-chrome-devtools

Next to append in Chrome Devtools autocomplete, there is a little `m`.  It shows up to various values that don't seem related.  For example; with the situation below, it also showed up next to `length`.

What is it?

[image: Next To Append]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [suggestion-subtitle](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/ui/SuggestBox.js?q=file:devtools+suggestion-subtitle+-file:test+-file:/Debug&sq=package:chromium&l=263&dr=C) that shows the item type when V8 engine can deduce it.

Sometimes you can see human-readable types such as Object, Node, Document, etc.
Sometimes it's derived from the prototype function and in your case minified jQuery library uses `m` class object (the letter is assigned randomly by the minification tool used to produce the bundle):

```js
m.each({
    appendTo: "append",
    prependTo: "prepend",
    insertBefore: "before",
    insertAfter: "after",
    replaceAll: "replaceWith"
}, function(e, t) {
    m.fn[e] = function(e) {
        var n, r = 0, i = [], o = m(e), a = o.length - 1;
        for (; a >= r; r++)
            n = r === a ? this : this.clone(!0),
            m(o[r])[t](n),
            h.apply(i, n.get());
        return this.pushStack(i)
    }
});
```

Effectively, `m` stands for `jQuery` class object, which is the returned type of `append` function.
If you would use the original non-minified jQuery library, the subtitle would display `jQuery`.